# Objective-C Implementing method in Base class with the child class type property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some code that I am trying to accomplish. I have a base class and some properties that are same for my child classes. Getter and setters needs to be implemented. In my child class I have a property and reference to it, `ExampleType &type`. `ExampleType` parent is `BaseType` witch cannot be instanced. Getter and setters in base class from my properties depend upon `BaseType`. So if I have in my base class something like this `BaseType *type`. Example of my getter:

```
-(NSString *) property {
    return self.type->returnString;
}
```

This really depends on my child property type `ExampleType`.I do not want to have copy/paste code in my child classes for properties. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide more context. You can reduce your existing code to a minimal example, that showcases the problem you are trying to solve. If I understood correctly, you have two inheritance trees, where the BaseType->ExampleType tree has a property of the same name?

Comment: They do not have same name. What I am trying to do, when I initialize my child class, I want to be able to just type childobject.property to access property in example which is inherited from base class, but that it recognizes that getter for property in base class now uses ExampleType instead of BaseType in self.type->returnString.

Comment: I have posted an answer, but if your situation differs from my sample code, please provide your class structure (in code), so we can better understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you wanted to accomplish. Here are the type classes:

```
@interface BaseType : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* returnString;

@end

@implementation BaseType
@end

@interface ExampleType : BaseType
@end

@implementation ExampleType

- (NSString *)returnString
{
    return @"returnString from ExampleType";
}

@end
```

And here are the main objects, incapsulating the type classes:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* property;

@end

@implementation Parent

- (BaseType*)type
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"should be implemented in child class");
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)property
{
    return self.type.returnString;
}

@end

@interface Child : Parent

@property (nonatomic, strong) ExampleType* type;

@end

@implementation Child

@end
```

So now you have a property `ExampleType` in your child class, and the `property` implementation is present only in the parent class.